# Nginx add_header only works when content type specified

Tags: nginx

I've got a location block in my Nginx config. looking like this:

```
location ~* "/Record\.([A-Za-z0-9]{4,6})$" {
        add_header Link "https://doi.org/xx.xxxxx/Record.$1; rel='cite-as'";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        if ($http_accept = 'application/ld+json') {
            rewrite "^/Record\.([A-Za-z0-9]{4,6})" /content_negotiation/jsonld/Record.$1 break; 
            proxy_pass https://api.example.org;
        }
        root /home/example.org/client/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

This is supposed to do two things:

1. If someone requests ld+json it will proxy a request to our API and return that to them.
2. If they do a HEAD request (e.g. with `curl -I`) it should add a 'cite-as' link to the headers.

The second of the above functions only works if I pass an ld+json request parameter. For example `curl -I 'https://example.org/Record.abc123'` gives:

```
server: nginx
date: Wed, 27 Sep 2023 10:32:28 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 1046
last-modified: Thu, 21 Sep 2023 13:28:40 GMT
etag: "650c4508-416"
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
accept-ranges: bytes
```

But running `curl -I -H 'Accept: application/ld+json' 'https://example.org/Record.abc123` gives:

```
server: nginx
date: Wed, 27 Sep 2023 10:33:41 GMT
content-type: application/ld+json; charset=utf-8
status: 200 OK
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
x-xss-protection: 0
maintenance: false
x-request-id: e1601dda-9833-4633-860e-327a664582f9
x-download-options: noopen
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-runtime: 0.029898
x-content-type-options: nosniff
read-only: false
x-powered-by: Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.15
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
access-control-allow-headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-Client-Id,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length,Content-Range,Maintenance,Read-Only
link: https://doi.org/xx.xxxxx/Record.9kahy4; rel='cite-as'
```

...a lot of which (e.g. the access-control-allow-methods) comes from the API.

Can anyone suggest why I'm not getting the `link` field with the default `curl -I` request?

Comment: Without Accept header try_files makes internal redirect to /index.html and, I guess, there is add_header directive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you saying that try_files causes the header to be removed again, somehow?

Comment: I guess you don't have file named `Record.abc123` in `/home/example.org/client/dist`, so `try_files` makes internal redirect to `/index.html` and nginx looks for a `location` that should handle this URI. Probably it's just `location /` or something like that. At this moment nginx forgets about `location ~* "/Record\.([A-Za-z0-9]{4,6})$"` and all directives inside it and acts like the request was `curl -I 'https://example.org/index.html'`.

Comment: Thanks. There's a javascript application in that directory, so that will handle the request for Record.abc123.
Is there any means I might perhaps set a header globally if that URL pattern is matched (the header has to include the ID from the URL)?

Comment: Why won't you just pass it always to `api.example.org` and let it check `Accept` header?

Comment: Because I'm looking for these specific effects: If the user reuquests the normal page, they get it with headers telling them where to find a JSON version (i.e. same URL but with different accept headers). Therefore, I need that URL to return the normal javascript page, but with headers added reflecting that JSON link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I managed to piece this together.

```
set $special_headers false;
set $special_link '';

location ~* "/Record\.([A-Za-z0-9]{4,6})$" {
  set $special_headers true;
  set $special_link "https://doi.org/xx.xxxxxx/$1; rel='cite-as'";
  # Api stuff if the user wants ld+json
  # try_files otherwise
}

location =/index.html {
  if ($special_headers = true) {
    add_header Link $special_link;
  }
}
```